# Avoid duplicate callings of CallBack<T>, Retrofit

Tags: android, callback, retrofit

I am working with the data of the GitHub api, using Retrofit. In one activity, I need need 2 references to the Retrofit Builder, hence - 2 callbacks. The calss' definition so far is:

```
public class UserScreen extends Activity implements Callback<GitHubUser>, Callback<GitHubRepos>
```

How can the duplicate class be avoided? My definition for the methods of the User call looks like that:

```
 public void loadData(View view) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();
     retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(GitHubUserAPI.ENDPOINT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
    GitHubUserAPI githubUserAPI = retrofit.create(GitHubUserAPI.class);

    Call<GitHubUser> callUser = githubUserAPI.getUser(newString);
    callUser.enqueue(this);

    Call<GitHubUser> callAvatar = githubUserAPI.getAvatar(newString);
    callAvatar.enqueue(this);

    Call<GitHubUser> callFollowers = githubUserAPI.getFollowers(newString);
    callFollowers.enqueue(this);

}


@Override
public void onResponse(Call<GitHubUser> call, final Response<GitHubUser> response) {
    final int code = response.code();
    if (code == 200) {
        final GitHubUser user = response.body();
       userNameTV.setText(user.getName());
        followersTV.setText("Followers: " + user.getFollowers());
        followingTV.setText("Following: " + user.getFollowing());



        ImageDownloader task = new ImageDownloader();
        Bitmap myImage;

        try {
            myImage = task.execute(user.getAvatar()).get();
            avatarImg.setImageBitmap(myImage);
            avatarImg.getLayoutParams().height=150;
            avatarImg.getLayoutParams().width=150;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}

public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return myBitmap;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<GitHubUser> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What duplicate class?

Comment: The intellisense' hint is : Duplicate class: retrofit2.Callback

Comment: I think you could use a generic type instead of User or Repo.

Comment: Pff, just blocked :/ May you help me with the declaration?